# Not able to get location change notification while in background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

My app needs location service to be used in background. So I added the following method

```
- (void)startStandardUpdates
{
    // Create the location manager if this object does not
    // already have one.
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

according to the [apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) document, it says that app will get notified when there is a change on location,ie `- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation`     delegate method will get called.

Inorder to make some background processing(extent the processing time) I have added `ExpirationHandler` within the above specified delegate method as follows

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;

    //Making webservice
    [self updateServerWithLongitude:longitude andLatitude:latitude];
}
```

and after completing the web service request I have stopped the background task as follows

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

Every thing will work as expected(able to get location change notification) if i haven't stopped background task after completing the web service request. But if i have stopped background task after completing the request, I am not able to get location change notification and location service icon in status bar goes away while application is in background.....

I have searched a lot to fix the problem...is this the correct way to get the location change and update the change to server while in background? if not can any one suggest a better way to do this? any help is greatly appreciated.....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be updated on location changes while the app is in the background, Apple requires you to specify the background mode of the app (**location** in this case) in the info.plist.

They key you need to use is [UIBackgroundModes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

Comment: thanks for you kind reply, but there is no point about enabling 'UIBackgroundModes' in apple's documentation about 'Location Awareness Programming Guide'. My application got rejected because of enabling 'UIBackgroundModes' in plist....any idea?

Comment: If you need your app to get location changes in the background (and process or use it in some way), you will need to have the background mode enabled. Apple rejects apps with background mode which just put it there (to make sure the app keeps running in the bkg) but don't use the mode really.

Comment: I am updating location to DB in locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLOcation method and it works fine as expected..is there any thing else to be implemented?